# How to connect Android Client with Node.js server using SocketIO?

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to connect with Node.js from Android Client using SocketIO but i am facing SocketTimeOutException in the Logcat.

MyCode:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.androidtestclient;

import io.socket.IOAcknowledge;
import io.socket.IOCallback;
import io.socket.SocketIO;
import io.socket.SocketIOException;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

try {
    SocketIO socket = new SocketIO("http://10.42.0.32:3000/");


    socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
                // display("Connectet  and " + json.toString(2));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
            System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
            // display("Connectet  and " + data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
            System.out.println("an Error occured");
            Log.d("error", "an error occured");
            // display("not Connectet == error occured ");
            socketIOException.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnect() {
            System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
            Log.e("disconnect", "Connection terminated");
            // display("disConnectet ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnect() {
            System.out.println("Connection established");
            Log.v("connect", "Connection established");
            // display("Connectet  and done");
        }

        @Override
        public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
            System.out
                    .println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
            Log.v("ON", "Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
            // display("Connectet  and " + event);
        }
    });

    // This line is cached until the connection is establisched.
    socket.send("Hello Server!");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

} }
```

**Node.js Code**

```
var http = require('http');
var io   = require('socket.io');
var app = http.createServer();

app.listen(3000);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

**Exception:**

```
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141): io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:322)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at io.socket.IOConnection.access$7(IOConnection.java:292)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:199)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141): Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:547)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:787)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:313)
12-07 15:28:53.396: W/System.err(4141):     ... 2 more
```

In the browser , i am able connect with localhost:3000 but facing issue in Android Client. I have also given my system IP address in the app.

Please suggest me some solution and please let me know.

Comment: SocketIO Doesn't like other services using it, the error with the handshake means it realizes you aren't using SocketIO. If you are then that is interesting

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your client is not supporting socket.io v1.0.x and your are using socket.io v1.0 in server side. you should downgrade your socket.io version on your server or change your library and use another one that supports v1 
if you are using android studio , you can use [this](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java) but if you are using eclipse, I don't know any library supporting socket.io v1